# Activating treeview navigation by CSOM?

Tags: csom, treeview

I was wondering if it would be possible to activate treeview navigation using CSOM? I know it can bedone using powershell (TreeViewEnabled), but that doesn't directly translate to CSOM - at least I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `TreeViewEnabled` of the CSOM SP Web object.

Try with the below sample code:

```
// auth code and get web logic

clientContext.Web.TreeViewEnabled = true;
clientContext.Web.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Using JSOM:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();

    web.set_treeViewEnabled(true);
    web.update()
    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        console.log("success");
    },function(){
        console.log("error");
    });

});
```

Using REST API:

```
var updateTreeView = JSON.stringify(
{  
    '__metadata': {   
         'type': 'SP.Web'   
    },
    'TreeViewEnabled': true
 }); 


$.ajax({
    url: "https://<your-site>/_api/web/",
    type: "POST",
    data: updateTreeView,
    headers: {  
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),    
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"  
    },  
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Reference  - [CSOM SP Web namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_members.aspx)

Comment: Hmm it seems I a little out of com comfortzone, would you be able to show me what a javascript function activating treeview would look like? Thanks!

Comment: updated answer to use JSOM :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, if the REST api works for this i might use that instead in the workflow which is creating the site in the first place! Can I assume REST api works for disabeling the "normal" quick launch as well?

Comment: yes, will work with quick launch as well.

Comment: That's very nice - it's quite odd though that inheriting top navigation isn't supported by REST then. I would expect it to be in the same ballpark, but that doesn't seem to be the case.